# Single letter recognition fails consitently

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am running some example custom processors to read values of governmental documents.
Some of the values we are after have a single letter as value, for example on a passport "Gender" has a value F or M. With a very high precision during labeling, this letter cannot be found by the tool provided. The labeling teams added the value manual but then the training of the processor fails with:

```
      "code": 3,
      "message": "Invalid document.",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
          "reason": "INVALID_DOCUMENT",
          "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
          "metadata": {
            "document": "XXX/61275_D88_FIN_46.JPG",
            "num_fields_needed": "1",
            "field_name": "entities.text_anchor.text_segments",
            "annotation_name": "Gender",
            "num_fields": "0"
          }
```

How to work with such cases as we have in many documents which single letter values we like to parse?